# Leaflet Turf.js - click to display distance along line

Tags: leaflet, turfjs

I use Turf.js along with Leaflet to plot a line/route on a map, display pins along the route and all other good things. Turf & Leaflet work great together and makes complex things pretty straight forward.

However, I now have a requirement to find the distance along the line/route based on a click event - and I can't quite work it out. So, if the route is say 100 miles long, I click at some point along the route - I'd like an alert to say '10.35 miles' or whatever the distance along happens to be.

Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated if anyone has a clue ?

Here's my current map turf/leaflet script :

```
        //path coords
        var coords = [<%=mapString%>];
        
        var map = L.map('map');  
    
        L.tileLayer(
            'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org" target=blank>OpenStreetMap</a> Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);
          
        var line = turf.lineString(coords);     
        var options = {units: 'miles'}; 
                
        // grab coord length
        var coordLen    = parseInt((line.geometry.coordinates.length) -1)       
                
        L.geoJSON(line).addTo(map);
                    
            // get bounds 
                var bbox = turf.bbox(line);
                var b0 = bbox[0];
                var b1 = bbox[1];
                var b2 = bbox[2];
                var b3 = bbox[3];                           

                var startIcon = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-stars-lv.png',                                    
                    iconSize:     [16, 16], // size of the icon
                });

                var endIcon = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-stars-lv.png',                                    
                    iconSize:     [16, 16], // size of the icon
                });

                L.marker([line.geometry.coordinates[0][1], line.geometry.coordinates[0][0]], {icon: startIcon}).addTo(map);
                L.marker([line.geometry.coordinates[coordLen][1], line.geometry.coordinates[coordLen][0]], {icon: endIcon}).addTo(map);
                                                
            map.fitBounds([[b1, b0],[b3, b2]]);

                map.on('click', function(e) {
                    var clickLat = (e.latlng.lat)
                    var clickLng = (e.latlng.lng)

                    L.marker(e.latlng, {icon: startIcon}).addTo(map);               

                    var sliced = turf.lineSlice([line.geometry.coordinates[0][0], line.geometry.coordinates[0][1]], [clickLng,clickLat], line);


                    L.geoJSON(sliced, {style: {color: "#ab13ba"}}).addTo(map);

                    })
```

Comment: Have you tried using [lineSlice](https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineSlice) to split the line in the point and measure the [length](https://turfjs.org/docs/#length) of the sliced line?

Comment: I haven't to be honest, but I'm not sure it' will work. I need to be able to dynamically click at any point on the plotted route/line and have it show me the distance from the start.

Comment: You will [click on the line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121482/click-events-with-leaflet-and-geojson) → get the coordinate you clicked, the line and the start coordinate of the line →​ pass it to lineSlice( line_start_coordinate, click_coordinate, line ) → this will return a line_from_start_to_click → pass it to length(line_from_start_to_click) → this will return your length.

Comment: Thanks - getting closer now. I've added in the map click event to grab the latLng and then run lineSlice - along with placing the lineSlice to the map in a different color. Whilst a new pin is added to the map, the slice doesn't seem to join back to the start point or end point for that matter ?? Not sure where I'm going wrong ??

Comment: Ok - the lineSlice function uses coords in a different order, so I switch them around and I now get a slice from the start to the clicked point - now, how to calc the slice distance ??

Comment: Got it ! Thanks Lucas for the direction - awesome !!

Answer (score 0):

The final step in this was thanks to direction from Lucas P.Luiz above - an onclick event that grabs the latLng position, hands it to Turf.JS to slice from the start position and then Turf.js again to calc the distance from the start to the click point.

```
                map.on('click', function(e) {
                    var clickLat = (e.latlng.lat)
                    var clickLng = (e.latlng.lng)                   
                    var sliced = turf.lineSlice([line.geometry.coordinates[0][0], line.geometry.coordinates[0][1]], [clickLng,clickLat], line);
                    L.geoJSON(sliced, {style: {color: "#ab13ba"}}).addTo(map);                  
                    var sliceLen = turf.length(sliced, {units: 'miles'});                   
                    alert(sliceLen.toFixed(3) + ' miles')
                    })
```